# Array sorting and truncating/separating them

Tags: python

I am trying to sort an array and separate it in python.

**Example**:

I have an data file like this that I will import:

```
x   y   z
1   3   83
2   4   38
8   1   98
3   87  93
4   1   73
1   3   67
9   9   18
1   4   83
9   3   93
8   2   47
```

I want it to first look like this:

```
x   y   z
1   3   83
1   3   67
1   4   83
2   4   38
3   87  93
4   1   73
8   1   98
8   2   47
9   9   18
9   3   93
```

So the `x` column is in ascending order, followed by the `y` column.

And then finally I want to build an array out of these arrays? Can I do that?

So I have:

```
array[0] = [[1, 3, 83],[1, 3, 67],[1, 4, 83]]
array[1] = [[2, 4, 38]]
array[2] = [[3, 87, 93]]
array[3] = [[4, 1, 73]]
array[4] = [[8, 1, 98],[8,2,47]]
```

and so on...

Starting out:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_file_name = 'whatever.dat'

data=np.loadtxt(data_file_name)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] so we can assist with the issues you are having in your implementation attempt?

Comment: Are you willing to use the Pandas package, or do you want a pure Python solution?

Comment: Pure python would be the best -- thank you kindly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a numpy solution (given that you used it for loading the data):

```
import numpy as np

data_file_name = 'whatever.dat'
data = np.loadtxt(data_file_name, 
                  skiprows=1, 
                  dtype=[('x', float), ('y', float), ('z', float)])

data.sort(axis=0, order=['x', 'y', 'z'])

unique_x_col_vals = set(row[0] for row in data)
array = {n: [list(row) for row in data if row[0] == val] 
            for n, val in enumerate(unique_x_col_vals)}

>>> array
{0: [[1.0, 3.0, 67.0], [1.0, 3.0, 83.0], [1.0, 4.0, 83.0]],
 1: [[2.0, 4.0, 38.0]],
 2: [[3.0, 87.0, 93.0]],
 3: [[4.0, 1.0, 73.0]],
 4: [[8.0, 1.0, 98.0], [8.0, 2.0, 47.0]],
 5: [[9.0, 3.0, 93.0], [9.0, 9.0, 18.0]]}
```

It uses a dictionary comprehension to generate the array, internally using a list comprehension to extract each row for the unique values based on column `x`.

I've used floats when importing the data, but you can also specify int if that matches your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas for this, with just couple lines of code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(txt, sep=r"\s*")
print df.sort(['x','y'], ascending=[True,True])
```

Comment: a pure python solution would be better for me on this particular case